# cannot enable ldap extension in php docker image

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, ldap, dockerfile

I am using docker images to build a wordpress website. Its using 3 images, php, wordpress and mysql.  One of the plugins I am using needs ldap extension installed and enabled. When I try to activate the plugin, it kept saying ldap is not installed. I got stuck and need help to get it working.

This is the yaml file.

```
            version: '3.3'

            services:
               php:
                 build: .
               wordpress:
                 depends_on:
                   - db
                 image: wordpress:latest
                 volumes:
                   - wordpress_files:/var/www/html
                 ports:
                   - "80:80"
                 restart: always
                 environment:
                   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
                   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
                   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 11111111

               db:
                 image: mysql:5.7
                 volumes:
                   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
                 restart: always
                 environment:
                   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 11111111
                   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
                   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
                   MYSQL_PASSWORD: 11111111
            volumes:
                wordpress_files:
                db_data:
```

This is the php docker image file.

```
            FROM php:7.4.1-fpm

            RUN \
                apt-get update && \
                apt-get install -y libicu-dev && \
                apt-get install libldap2-dev -y && \
                docker-php-ext-install intl && \
                docker-php-ext-enable intl && \ 
                docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ && \
                docker-php-ext-install ldap && \
                docker-php-ext-enable ldap
```

Comment: Which plugin is not installed?

Comment: image wordpress:latest ldap not found

Comment: php -m     
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imagick
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache

Comment: [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) 
Read "Adding additional libraries / extensions"

Answer (score 0):

The docker image for php/wordpress does not provide any additional PHP extensions or other libraries, even if they are required by popular plugins.

> There are an infinite number of possible plugins, and they potentially
> require any extension PHP supports. Including every PHP extension that
> exists would dramatically increase the image size.
>
> If you need additional PHP extensions, you'll need to create your own
> image FROM this one. The [documentation of the php image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/php/README.md#how-to-install-more-php-extensions) explains how
> to compile additional extensions.
>
> Additionally, the [wordpress
> Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/618490d4bdff6c5774b84b717979bfe3d6ba8ad1/apache/Dockerfile#L5-L9) has an example of doing this.

cf. [docker/wordpress documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Dockerfile in your docker-compose.yml

try the following in docker-compose.yml:

```
wordpress:
  depends_on:
    - db
  image: 
    context: .
    dockerfile: relative/path/to/your/Dockerfile
  container_name: wordpress
  volumes:
    - wordpress_files:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  restart: always
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: 11111111
```